# Asp.Net - Can not Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors from Nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to Install "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -Version 5.0.0" from Nuget on my Asp.net WebApi Project.

But it install fail and have some error mrssage：

```
An error occurred while sending the request.Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Error Picture：
[image]

How can I Install it? thanks.

Comment: It looks like your behind a proxy as you can't connect to remote server. Try the command in a public network

Comment: @MarcusH Thanks， It's OK now.